# How to click an element in a node tree using excel visual basic

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I'm trying to automate one task I'm doing using Excel VBA and I have no problem to send the data I need to the webpage however in the webpage there is a node tree and to make my code works a selection needs to be selected before sending the data to the webpage to fill the information and I don't know how to select the element in that node tree. I tried get element by id but didn't help. The tree has about 18 elements and here is the code for one of its elements:

```
<span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Credit And Rebill</span></a>
```

I tried this code `doc.getElementById("nd_17").Click` but didn't work for me.
Any help will be appreciated

The VBA code I'm using so far to fill the data is

```
Sub testing()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "www.example.com"

    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Set doc = IE.document

    doc.getElementById("nd_17").Click
    doc.getElementById("credit_and_rebill_bill_id").Value = "test"


End Sub
```

The full tree code is

```
<div class="x-tree-root-node"><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-31" class="x-tree-node-el x-unselectable x-tree-node-expanded" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-end-minus"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Tools</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="position: static; visibility: visible; display: block; left: auto; top: auto; z-index: auto;" id="ext-gen361"><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="nd_01" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Settle Invoice</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="nd_02" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Forgive Charges</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="nd_03" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable x-tree-selected" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Refund Charges</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="nd_04" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Regenerate Invoices</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="nd_05" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Split Charge</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="nd_06" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Transfer Charge</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="nd_07" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Advance Payment</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="nd_08" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Fetch FX Rate</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="nd_09" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">OCB Injection</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="nd_10" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Cancel Payment</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="nd_11" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Check Bank Account</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="nd_12" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Bulk Subscription Retry</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="nd_13" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Bulk Invoice Regeneration</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="nd_14" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">E Invoice Customer Onboard</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="nd_15" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">E Invoice Customer Lookup</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="nd_16" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Retry Invoices On PayByInvoice PI</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="nd_17" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Credit And Rebill</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="nd_18" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-end"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Check Credit And Rebill Status</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li></ul></li></div>
```

Comment: There is no *id* `nd_17`. It's an *attribute* with the *name* `ext:tree-node-id` and the *value* `nd_17`. You can try it with `doc.querySelector("div[ext:tree-node-id='nd_17']").Click` But it will only work if the div tag has a click event. Look here to learn more about `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the below HTML code of a node that you want to click.

```
<span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Credit And Rebill</span></a>
```

You can try to loop through all the anchor tags and try to match the class name and tab index attribute and inner text value. If it gets matched then you can click the element.

Example:

```
Sub test()

    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim elements, element, attr
    Dim item As String

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True

    URL = "D:\Tests\16.html"

    IE.Navigate URL

    Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until

    Set elements = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

    For Each element In elements

        If element.className = "x-tree-node-anchor" And element.tabIndex = "1" And element.innerText Like "*Credit And Rebill*" Then
            element.Click
        End If
    Next element


    Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Further, you can modify the code example as per your own requirements.

Comment: Thank you so much, this does help. However I end up with a small problem which is I have 2 tabs opened (Credit And Rebil) and (Check Credit And Rebil) - Is there a way to change the Like operator to be equal only?
Or How can I make the code as well click the X sign in this code 
      ` <a class="x-tab-strip-close" id="ext-gen227"></a> `

Comment: I've made it :) - just needed to remove the * from "Credit And Rebill"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to click on the options via anchor elements then you can use `nth-of-type`. You need to specify which option you want to click. You could create a dictionary which automatically collects the relevant visual text for the anchors e.g. `Settle Invoice` and then add the appropriate indices e.g. 1 as values for the dict. You could do this easily by populating a dictionary in a loop from `0 to ie.document.querySelector(".x-tree-node-ct .x-tree-node .x-tree-node-anchor").Length -1` and simply add + 1 to the loop counter to get the appropriate index value to insert into dict. Use the indexed item from the nodeList returned and take the `.innerText` to get the keys.

Generically:

```
ie.document.querySelector(".x-tree-node-ct .x-tree-node:nth-of-type(n) .x-tree-node-anchor")
```

where `n` would be the appropriate index.

Selecting the 1st of 19, as described above would thus be:

```
ie.document.querySelector(".x-tree-node-ct .x-tree-node:nth-of-type(1) .x-tree-node-anchor").click
```

Comment: Hey @QHarr, I got a question for you. Can I use `Html.querySelector()` after I define `Set Html = CreateObject("HTMLFile")`? Thanks.